# How are Electoral College electors chosen for write-in votes for President?

Tags: united-states, voting, presidential-election, electoral-college

In the United States, when people vote for president, they actually vote for the electors. For instance, the Ohio ballot says the following:

> *"A vote for any candidates for President and
>   Vice President shall be a vote for the
>   electors of those candidates whose names
>   have been certified to the Secretary of State."*

How are Elector College electors chosen for write-in votes for President? Say that miraculously a write-in candidate got 51% of the vote. Would an elector for them be chosen after the vote? If not, does that mean that write-in candidates can never receive electoral votes, despite what ballots say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Some facts

- Only 43 states allow write-in candidates, so that's access to 494 electoral votes.
- In these states - Alabama, Delaware, Iowa, New Hampshire, New Jersey, Oregon, Vermont and Wyoming, write-in candidates do not need to be registered; voter can virtually vote for anyone they like.

#### How are Elector College electors chosen for write-in votes for President?

According to the [State of Maine Gov Write-in Candidate Requirements](http://www.maine.gov/sos/cec/elec/candidate/wirequir2016.doc), a write-in candidate is required to name his/her 4 electors during registration. (Maine has 4 electoral votes)

> A presidential write-in candidate must name the candidate’s four electors when the Declaration of Write-in Candidacy is submitted.

So, in Maine, they are chosen by the candidate himself/herself.

For other states, some have clear guidelines, while others aren't that clear. You may want to check out [this article](http://www.electoral-vote.com/evp2016/Feature_stories/write-ins.html) for elaboration.

#### If not, does that mean that write-in candidates can never receive electoral votes, despite what ballots say?

They can receive electoral votes in states that allows write-in candidates. However it has never happened, so I don't think that the process is super clear in all states. Only some specified the process in registration forms. Write-in candidates don't really have a large chance of winning any state in the first place.

#### Say that miraculously a write-in candidate got 51% of the vote. Would an elector for them be chosen after the vote?

[This article](http://www.electoral-vote.com/evp2016/Feature_stories/write-ins.html) does have a hypothetical example at the end, quite interesting to check it out since the example surely would be better than I coming up with one.

Comment: This answer appears to be incomplete. Maine is just one of the 43 states. Other states have different rules.

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be different in every state.  Note that in most states write-in candidates have to register.  I suspect that in those states that require registration, they choose the electors at the same time.  In other states they might have to pass a law for it, as it has never happened.  Note that 51% isn't necessary.  40% might be enough this year.  In Utah, even 30%.

You mention Ohio.  In Ohio, write-in candidates have to be [certified](http://www.dispatch.com/content/stories/local/2016/10/25/18-candidates-eligible-in-ohio-for-write-in-votes.html).  According to the [Ohio Revised Code](http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/3513.041):

> In addition, candidates for president and vice-president of the United States shall also file with the secretary of state by that seventy-second day a slate of presidential electors sufficient in number to satisfy the requirements of the United States constitution.

If they don't, then they'd fail certification and would not be eligible for write-in in Ohio.